# Disable Charles for iOS app

Tags: ios, charles-proxy

Is there any way to stop **Charles**, for not tracking the request and response of the app because, it basically shows that parameters too which should not be seen by others.

Comment: The easiest way to disable Charles from using your app is to simply lock your iPhone and not give Charles the unlock code. Therefore, this disables his ability to use any app, including your app.

Comment: But if someone is using my application and with the help of Charles, it basically hack into my data. How could i stop those people.

Comment: @user3559198, encrypt it, if the data is sensitive.

Comment: Is there any way to know that the WIFI we using is on proxy or not?

Comment: Use HTTPS and pin the certificates. This way the man in the middle attack should not be possible. You might also want to go thru the certificate chain yourself and if there are none valid certificates cancel the request.

Comment: @user3559198, encrypt the data, if it is sensitive.